# cant figure out how to cross compile using docker container

Tags: go, docker

I am trying to cross compile some Go code to a windows target (based on this guide https://hub.docker.com/_/golang/):

```
$ docker run --rm -v "$PWD":/usr/src/myapp -w /usr/src/myapp -e GOOS=windows -e GOARCH=386 golang:1.5 go get github.com/gorilla/websocket && go build -v
conn.go:8:2: cannot find package "github.com/gorilla/websocket" in any of:
/usr/lib/go/src/github.com/gorilla/websocket (from $GOROOT)
/home/mark/devel/gocode/src/github.com/gorilla/websocket (from $GOPATH)
```

I try to compile this: https://github.com/gorilla/websocket/tree/master/examples/chat) 
...but I can not figure out the correct command line :(

Comment: `-i` runs `go install` . If you need to fetch the dependencies, you need `go get`

Comment: my troubleshooting attempt went into the wrong direction - I can see that now. I am going to rewrite the question...

Comment: You need the toolchain built for the target platform. There used to be images tagged with `-cross` which had the toolchain pre-built for cross compilation, but it seems they no longer provide those.

Comment: my understanding is that they do not provide the xy-cross containers since this is covered by the standard ones. The error message does not indicate anything missing in the toolchain.

Comment: Oh, you're right. The problem is your executing `go build` locally, not in the container.